# Displaying QGIS plugin icons without resources.py file?

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-plugins, pyqt4

I am working on a new QGIS plugin and I am trying to comply with the requirement below. The full requirement is located [here](https://plugins.qgis.org/).

> - source repository is in good shape:
>
>   - no generated file is left in repository (ui_*.py, resources_rc.py, gen. help files…)

I have a resources.py file.

If I remove resources.py file, no icon will be shown. So how can I achieve the visibility of resources without a resources.py file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although it may not be good pythonic practice, you don't actually always need a resources.py file. For icons, you can reference them directly in your PyQGIS code. For example, if you have a QToolButton named 'MyToolButton', you can associate a PNG-format icon with via a statement like

MyToolButton.setIcon(QIcon("c:/icons/sample_icon.png"))

Comment: Thank you. It works! I got the home dir using `HOME = expanduser("~")` and added '.qgis/python/plugins/[myplugin]' and it works.